# Calculating sum per id using UpdateCursor of ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am trying to calculate the SUM value for (VD_SUM) Based on Basin ID and output in the field "VD_SUM_SUM".
I am not sure how to write the SUM part at the end.

This is what I have so far.

```
import arcpy

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor('Streams_Geology_R1', ["BASIN_ID", "VD_SUM", "VD_SUM_SUM"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[2] = row[1].sum???? based on basin ID 
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Use summary statistics then join output to your table.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot and example of what results you want?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to sum all values by basin ID. Use a dictionary. Use the basin ID as your key. Add values to your dictionary in an initial iteration of your table. Then iterate your table again and update your table.

```
import arcpy

#dictionary for storing values
di = {}
#iterate table
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('Streams_Geology_R1', ["BASIN_ID", "VD_SUM", "VD_SUM_SUM"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        #get basin id
        bid = row [0]
        #get value
        vdsum = row [1]
        #try adding value to existing key indictionary
        try: di [bid] += vdsum
        #add key and value to dictionary
        except KeyError: di [bid] = vdsum

#update table
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor ('Streams_Geology_R1', ["BASIN_ID", "VD_SUM_SUM"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        #get sum
        row [1] = di [row [0]]
        #update row
        cursor.updateRow (row)
```

Comment: Great thank you it works! I dont understrand all of the code however. What does try: di  [bid] += vdum mean? &  except Keyerror: di [bid] = vdsum? Is this the part that does the Summing? Also on update curser what does the di part mean?

Comment: Sorry that reads bad, basically which part in that script actually tells it to Sum the VD_SUM based on Basin ID?